# How to make auto-run python file when windows open

Tags: python, regedit, autorun

```
from datetime import date

bugun = str(date.today())

if bugun == "2021-04-25":
    with open("dosya.py","r+") as dosya:
        liste = dosya.readlines()
        liste.insert(3,"DenemeBu\n")
        del liste[4]
        dosya.seek(0)
        print(liste)
        with open("dosya.py","w") as dosya:
            for i in liste:
                dosya.write(i)
```

```
import os
print("Hello")
sayi1 = int(input("Sayi1: "))
sayi2 = int(input("Sayi2: "))
print("Sonuc {}".format(sayi1+sayi2))
```

I want to change second file with first file but I want first file to open when my pc opens and takes current date. When date corrects and changes second file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your startup folder by pressing Win + R and typing in shell:startup

Within this folder, create a txt file and rename it to anything.bat and edit it with

```
@ECHO OFF
python3 C:/path/to/my/script.py
```

You can remove the "@ECHO OFF" if you want it to have a terminal window popup.

EDIT: As for the error you're facing.
Change

```
open("dosya.txt", "r")
```

to

```
open("C:/full/path/to/dosya.txt", "r")
```

Do that everywhere you open dosya.txt, like at the dosya.txt write below

You're facing this error because you're running the command for the script from a directory that doesn't contain that file and it tries to find that file in it's running directory and can't find it. Setting the full path to it will make the script work if run from any directory on your computer.

Comment: I tried it and I am facing with error. Cmd opens and cloeses fast. I think I saw "most recent call " I cannot even see which error

Comment: That error means that your script has exited with an error code

Comment: I did understand the error. 2 python files in the same directory, they are in the desktop but when I try to execute first file from cmd I face with this error"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mehmet\Desktop\dosya_zamanlayici.py", line 6, in <module>
    with open("dosya.txt","r+") as dosya:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'dosya.txt'" They are in same directory. How it possible. Do I mistake with coding?

Comment: @Deneme Change open("dosya.txt...) to open(C:/full/path/to/dosya.txt)
When the command is executed from elsewhere, the script tries to find that file in the folder it's being run from. If you run it from C:/ or C:/Users/Desktop and that file is not in there, it won't run.

Answer (score 1):

I have written a script that can auto-run any script when PC starts

```
import os
import winreg


class is_at_startup:
    '''Adding the given program path to startup'''

    def __init__(self, program_path):
        self.program_path = program_path
        self.program_basename = os.path.basename(self.program_path)

    def main(self):
        '''Adding to startup'''

        if os.path.exists(self.program_path):
            areg = winreg.ConnectRegistry(None, winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER)

            try:
                akey = winreg.OpenKey(areg, f'SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run\\{self.program_basename}', 0, winreg.KEY_WRITE)
                areg.Close()
                akey.Close()

                print(f'{self.program_path} already at startup')

            except WindowsError:
                key = winreg.OpenKey(areg, r'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run', 0, winreg.KEY_SET_VALUE)
                winreg.SetValueEx(key, f'{self.program_basename}', 0, winreg.REG_SZ, f'{self.program_basename}')

                areg.Close()
                key.Close()

                print(f'{self.program_path} added to startup')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    startup = is_at_startup('your program path')
    startup.main()
```

> If you are using python 2.7.x then replace **winreg** with **_winreg**

Comment: Again I am facing with error. file opens but closes fast with error. I cannot see error because it closes fast

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this way for .bat files, and it worked you can also try. Put your python files that you want to run on windows startup at this location.
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp

Comment: I tried, file opened but nothing happened. I looked dosya.py and it didn't changed but when I open first file manually it works. I don't understand why

Comment: Hope you have placed both files at same placed. Even you can try Windows task scheduler as well. Run on startup. May It would help

Comment: They both placed in Desktop but when I try to execute this command C:\Users\Me > python C:\Users\Me\Desktop\myfile.py I face with this error"Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\Mehmet\Desktop\dosya_zamanlayici.py", line 6, in <module> with open("dosya.txt","r+") as dosya: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'dosya.txt" but when I try to execute from C:\Users\Me\Desktop > python C:\Users\Me\Desktop\myfile.py it runs

Comment: Oh. Please use Windows task scheduler and use same desktop location which it is running successfully flag as run on startup. Hope it will solve your problem.